# On what domain is my Javascript in my Office Add-In

Tags: web-services, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook Add-In which runs in OWA.

- The Manifest sits on https://company.ourdomain.com
- The Javascript sits on https://company.ourdomain.com
- The Custom Web Service we wrote in-house sits on https://company.ourdomain.com

When I make a call from within JavaScript in response to an Add-In Command, I use the format https://company.ourdomain.com/api/Controller/Action in the ajax call.

I end up getting one of those CORS errors (sometimes it's pre-flight, other times CORB).  Why am I getting this if the Javascript is literally sitting on the same domain as the web service?

I'm assuming I'm authenticated since I've logged into my Outlook account.

What gives?

NOTE:
As an experiment I attempted a RESTful call by directly typing in the URL (No OWA involved).   This caused the code to Authenticate against Azure AD.  Then afterward I logged into OWA in the same browser session and everything worked fine.   Do I actually need to authenticate within the Javascript even if the webservice I'm calling is in the same domain?

**AJAX CALL WHICH GENERATES ERROR**
Remember, it will work just fine after I've made a RESTful call by making a call to my web service directly from the Browser

```
    var apiUri = '/api/People/ShowRecord';


$.ajax({
    url: apiUri,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(serviceRequest),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (response) {
    if (!response.isError) {
        // response to successful call
    }
    else {
        // ... 
    }
}).fail(function (status) {
    // some other response
}).always(function () {

    console.log("Completed");
});
```

**OBSERVATION**
When I call the api from the Address Bar the code below is run.   This code never gets invoked by Javascript

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(EEWService.AuthStartup))]

namespace EEWService
{
    public partial class AuthStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        { app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {

                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Whr = "ourdomain.com";
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },

                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:MetadataAddress"],
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] { $"spn:{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]}" }
                }
            });


        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:MetadataAddress"],
            });

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ideally this should not be the case, Can you please share the exact CORS Error message.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT:  **Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx=wsignin1.0&whr=ourdomain.com: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://company.ourdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: FYI, regarding your Observation, your AuthStartup code is only called once at startup for configuring authentication -- startup may happen only at the first request to the API after updating it or restarting it. This means subsequent requests to the API will not trigger execution that code.

Comment: I've stumbled across ADAL.js.  This may do the trick for me.

Comment: Getting ADALjs to work with Outlook is not as simple as I thought.  Are there any samples that use it with Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with this I think.

The first one is you are trying to serve your static content off the same server you are serving your code from. This is in general considered a bad-practice, purely because no point in wasting those precious server resources for static content. Ideally you should upload your static content to a CDN - and let the users' browser make a request to some super-cached file server. However - I understand this option might not be available to you as of now. This also isn't the root cause.

The second and the real problem is, (you think you are but) you are not authenticated. Authentication in Outlook web-addins doesn't come by default, it's something you need to handle. When Outlook loads your web add-in into the side panel it makes certain methods available to you which you can use and kind-of create a pseudo-identity (as an example [`Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.userprofile#emailaddress-string) ) - but if you want real authentication, you will need to do that yourself.

There are three ways of doing that as far as I can tell.

1. The first one is through the [Exchange Identity Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/inside-the-identity-token)
2. Second one is through the [Single Sign On feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)
3. The third one - which I think is the most convenient and the simplest in logic to implement is using WebSockets. ([SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.2) might be what you need).

   - When the user loads your first page, make sure a JS value like `window.Unique_ID` available to them. This will come in handy.
   - Have a button in your UI - which reads "Authenticate"
   - When the user clicks to this button, you pop them out to a url which will redirect to your authentication URL. (Something like https://company.ourdomain.com/redirToAuth). This would save you the trouble of getting blocked in the side-panel, because you are using `window.open` with a url that's on your domain. Pass that Unique_ID to redirection which then redirects you to OAuth login URL. That should look like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/......&state=Unique_ID`
   - Right after popping the user to sign in window, in your main JS (which is client-side), you open a web-socket to your server, again with that Unique_ID and start listening.
   - When the user completes authentication, the OAuth flow should post back either an access token, or the code. If you get the access token, you can send it through the sockets to front-end (using the Unique_ID which is in the parameters of post-back) or if you had the code, you finish authenticating the user with a server-to-server call and pass the access token the same way afterwards. So you use that unique Id to track the socket that user connected from and relay access token to **only** that user.

Comment: Thank You Mavi, for such a thorough reply.  You've confirmed my suspicions about the authentication.   I'll look into what you've written and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Would appreciate the green tick when you think it qualifies as the answer :)

Comment: I ended up using the Exchange Identity Token.   It was the best fit for what I'm doing.  All the options you gave me were VERY instructive.  It's what I need to be reading right now.
My apologies for the time it took to respond.

Comment: For anyone else interested in dealing with the different token types and how to validate them inside of your Office Add-In, there's an instructive project on Git Hub

[Token Viewer Example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-In-Token-Viewer)